# emacs windows compiler files permissions

Tags: windows, emacs, compiler-construction

I have a problem when compiling shared libraries and executables using emacs on Windows

The permissions on the files that the compiler is producing are such that I cannot recompile the code as it cannot overwrite the previous .dll or .exe

Currently I am having to go in and delete the files manually via explorer before I can recompile

never had this issue under linux

anyone know of a workaround as all this manual file deleting is getting tedious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't a file permissions thing. The problem was that gdb under windows (as provided by MinGW) locks the executable and any associated shared libraries when it is running so you can't recompile the executable or any of the shared libraries whilst gdb is running. This is not the case when doing the same thing under linux. All you need do under under windows is stop the debugger with `k` then recompile then start it again.